# Как работает #include &#60;iostream>

Tags: c++, компиляция, препроцессор

Недавно решал тренировочный вариант ОГЭ по информатике и нашёл вот такую задачу:

```
#include &#60;iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int s,t;
   cin >> s;
   cin >> t;
   if (s > 10 || t > 10)
      cout << "ДА";
   else
      cout << "НЕТ";
return 0;
}
```

> Было проведено 9 запусков программы...

(текст дальше опущу, к вопросу это отношения не имеет)

---

Стало интересно, что это за строчка такая (вижу такое впервые):

```
#include &#60;iostream>
```

Решил показать это компилятору:

- gcc/clang

  > error: #include expects "FILENAME" or 
  > #include <iostream>
- vc++

  > error C2006: '#include': expected a filename, found '&'
  > fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory

---

Тестировал [здесь](https://rextester.com/), флаги не трогал, оставил те, что предоставил сайт.

Можно ли скомпилировать такое под c++, и если можно, то чем оно отличается от

```
#include <iostream>
```

---

Задача взята [отсюда](https://yandex.ru/tutor/subject/problem/?problem_id=T9598)

Comment: lol. `&#60;` — это десятичный код символа `<`... с c++ это ни как не связано — просто кривая конвертация в HTML на конкретном ресурсе...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#60;` — это закодированный в стиле HTML [знак меньше](https://unicode-table.com/ru/003C/). 60 в десятичной системе — код символа в таблице Unicode. Из-за ошибки отображения вы не видите сам символ.